# Which functions of two variables have a constant ratio of $\partial f/\partial \ln(x)$ and $\partial f/\partial \ln(y)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

What is the most generic function $f(x,y)$ on $(\mathbb{R}^+)^2$ that satisfies the partial differential equation
$$\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial \ln(y)}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial \ln(x)}} := \frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}} \frac{y}{x} = \mathrm{const.}?$$

One set of solutions takes the form $f(x,y) = a x^\alpha y^\beta$, because the numerator and denominator of the fraction are each individually constant. But I doubt this is the most general form of such an $f$; is there a more general family of functions $f$ where the numerator and denominator vary individually, but their ratio is constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite this condition as $cx\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$, where $c\in\Bbb{R}$. The flow of the vector field $L:=cx\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ is given by
\begin{align}
\Phi_t(x,y)=(xe^{ct},ye^{-t}).
\end{align}
We have that $L(f)=0$ if and only if for all $t$, $\Phi_t^*f=f$, i.e $f=f\circ\Phi_t$, which simply means that for each point $(x,y)$, $f$ has to be constant along the curves $t\mapsto \Phi_t(x,y)$. You should try sketching these integral curves (when $c=0$ they’re just vertical lines, modulo some degenerate singleton ‘curves’ on the $x$-axis).

Since you only care about the region $(\Bbb{R}_+)^2$, we can take powers freely. Observe that along these curves, we have that for all $t$, $\frac{xe^{ct}}{(ye^{-t})^{-c}}=xy^c$. In other words, the quantity $xy^c$ remains constant along these curves. So, if $f$ is a (sufficiently differentiable) function of $xy^c$ alone (i.e there is a sufficiently differentiable $F:(0,\infty)\to\Bbb{R}$ such that for all $(x,y)\in (\Bbb{R}_+)^2$, $f(x,y)=F(xy^c)$), then $f$ satisfies the PDE $L(f)=0$.

So, for example, $f(x,y)=\sin(xy^c)$, or $f(x,y)=\cosh(\arctan(xy^c))$ etc all work (in the case $c=\frac{\beta}{\alpha}$ and $F(s)=as^{\alpha}$, we recover $f(x,y)=ax^{\alpha}y^{\beta}$, which is the example you cited).

Comment: You can avoid all the flow stuff by noting that $\nabla f$ is parallel to $(y,cx)$, and so level curves of $f$ are solutions of $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = -\dfrac y{cx}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin funnily enough, that’s what I did initially, but I found that ODE and got stuck… I really should get over my fear of ODEs

Comment: Hint: it’s homogeneous, so let $u=y/x$. (Think blowing up if that helps. ;))

Comment: yup in hindsight it’s obvious. (I spent 3 seconds looking at the ODE, couldn’t figure it out then, so I said nope and used the biggest hammer I could find to solve the problem:)

Comment: Not to lecture or anything, but often we must gauge the knowledge base of the OP and try to respond accordingly.

Comment: @TedShifrin that’s a very fair point. OP (and future readers) now have your first comment to go off of as well :)

Comment: You can also solve the ODE by simply separating variables.